# What is the browser support for scrollWidth property

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am viewing the documentation for this property on MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth

In the browser compatibility section it states unknown for most browsers. I did test it and it seem to work fine on all of the modern browsers I have currently installed, but I am a bit concerned for the unknown part in MDN docs.

Did you had any issues with this property in any browser? Do you have another trustworthy resource with browser compatibility matrix?

Comment: Although the scrollWidth property has been around for a decade, and has been widely used, the one thing you might want to watch out for in old browsers is the data type. In various revisions of the CSSOM View spec, it has been specified as float, double, long and currently int.